# Is it okay to allow orders to be placed in rails web app without session data or users class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, authentication

I have a question for a project I am working on. I am working on a RoR project in which a site is selling a single type of item, a book. The person I am creating this for does not want to deal with users creating user account to check out as the sales season is very short for this product, the purchases are done once per year, and the site only sells a single item.

I am wondering if there is something wrong with the implementation I am thinking of. What I was envisioning was a single database class called Orders. visitors to the site would simple fill out an order form with payment details through stripe and click submit. If they payment clears, the order with all the Orders information would be persisted to the DB. If the payment fails then it is not persisted and the relevant error information is displayed in using flash.

I suppose the meat of my question is; is there anything inherently 'wrong' about implementing this model without a users class and just having visitors to the site place orders?

I am a fairly new developer and this is my first big project so any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: This is mostly a business decision rather than a technical decision. If it's fine to your business, then its also fine technically. With that being said, check whether you might want to re-use the order data next year to ease up another sale to the same people. Also, make sure you get all the necessary permissions from the user to store that data. But again, all of those are business decisions which we can't help you with here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirements say that it is okay, then it is okay, if your requirements say it is not okay, then it is not okay.

There's not more to say, since only you know what your requirements are.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was thinking as well. But for my first big project I wanted to run this by more people haha.